# "reload ~/.bash_profile"error by installing virtualenvwrapper

Tags: bash, command-line, virtualenvwrapper

The virtualenvwrapper official documents ask me to add three lines to ~/.bash_profile, but I add three wrong lines to there, and then, there is an error looks like below after I reloaded by command`source ~/.bash_profile`

```
/Users/donald/.bash_profile:1: bad assignment
```

Can anyone tell me how to do and why? and if someone can teach me how to install **virtualenvwrapper**? I have spent a whole night working on this and fail.

The three wrong command lines are:

```
export WORKON_HOME=~/Envs
mkdir -p $WORKON_HOME
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

Comment: And the lines are?

Comment: @MikeVelazco $ export WORKON_HOME=~/Envs
$ mkdir -p $WORKON_HOME
$ source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh

Comment: I don't know if you know it but you don't have to put the dolar sign on the bash_profile file

Comment: @MikeVelazco oh...I put the dolar sign to split the command lines which is easier to read it.

Comment: Only as a comment, check that the files and directories exist

Comment: @MikeVelazco and I don't know what the command lines mean, but I want to know and how can I know about it?

Comment: I try to use `command + shift + G`to enter .bash_profile in finder, but the computer do nothing.

Comment: @andlrc is that right?with the three-lines code

Comment: Try with this gist: https://gist.github.com/MikeVelazcoMtz/7a84f0e574db62d3eb08

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's just a simple question, I found the answer later.

After you add wrong command lines to .bash_profile , you can use the command lines below to get a easy-editing window

```
touch ~/.bash_profile
open -e ~/.bash_profile
```

then you will know how to do.

And...

If you are confused with installing virtualenvwrapper, have a look on this:

virtualenvwrapper.sh is not in `/usr/local/bin`, you can use the command line below to find where is it.

```
which virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

After that, you can copy the **virtualenvwrapper.sh** to `/usr/local/bin` or change the path after *source* command in the **.bash_profile**.

Remember to reload the **.bash_profile** with the command line below everytime you use virtualenvwrapper.

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Thanks~!